delete interior of stl files
I'm looking for an option to delete all interior faces of an STL for printing. Sometimes when I will get a stl ready for print I found out it have inside forms.(like samples on the image) Didn't find any solution on Blender to keep only the exterior, Tried 'selection all by trait' to have interior faces but don't work on this case..there's something easy that keeps only the'visual geometry' and delet all the rest?
Edit: my question was closed saying is similar cases where the author wanted to cut intersection of two separated objects with the solution beeing a bolean modifier. But this is not my case.
The boolean modifier to cut one piece using other don't apply to my problem. I did see topics with the same problem but without solution. Thank you.


This is quite an old post but there doesn't seem to be anything else here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162884/blender-2-81-hollow-model-for-3d-printing

thanks for the reply, I checked the aswers on this one but seems not quite solved also, as with the original author, the closest I got was also with the vox remesh tool....but really weird solution and with my attempts it worked with one stl but not with other for some reason. still thinking there's an easier way around I'm not seeing.

Voxel Remesh will deform your topology a bit, the best is probably to try Boolean, I'm afraid there's no other solution

Thinking about it, I suppose you could try selecting all the outer vertices by painting over them in Vertex mode with the Circle Select (C key) option in Edit mode, turning the object to try to get all of them. Then use Ctrl-I to invert the selection and X to delete the vertices. That should get rid of most of the internal structure but you'd have to be very thorough selecting the outer vertices and it might miss a few.

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/how-to-intersect-objects-and-delete-leftover-internal-planes/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18916/how-to-remove-interior-faces-while-keeping-exterior-faces-untouched https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/removing-internal-geometry https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/removing-internal-geometry-before-3d-printing

my question was closed saying is equal these ones but in these cases the author wanted to cut intersection of two separated objects and the aswer was to use a bolean modifier to cut one piece with other, this is nothing similar with my case.
